# Extending Exceptions in Powershell with default message

Tags: powershell, exception, extending

I have been trying to wrap my head around extending Exceptions in PowerShell. My first pass at a class looks like this...

```
class CustomException : Exception {
    CustomException () {
    }
    CustomException ([String] $message) : base ($message) {
    }
}
```

And use is as expected, with the first approach here producing the type name, and the second the provided message...

```
try {
    throw [CustomException]
} catch {
    "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
try {
    throw [CustomException] 'Another message'
} catch {
    "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

However, I really want to have a default message, so I can use the first example in many places, but if I want to revise the message I can do it the one time in the class. Or perhaps even localize the message at some point. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695482/setting-the-message-of-a-custom-exception-without-passing-it-to-the-base-constru) seems to suggest it's possible in C#, especially the last two posts. So, taking the last example there...

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException () : base("This is my Custom Exception Message")
    {
    }
}
```

I thought I could do the same in Powershell, like so...

```
CustomException () : base ('Default message') {
}
```

But I still get the type name when not providing a message. That got me thinking, and I tried...

```
try {
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]
} catch {
    "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

And that ALSO doesn't provide a default message, just the class name. So, is that C# code not doing what I think it's doing? Or is this just a difference in behavior in Powershell? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Weird, adding `: base("default message")` to the default constructor works perfectly fine for me. What exact version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I'm in 5.1. I finally weaned myself off 2.0, but I can't force people into Core.

Comment: I just noticed what was missing, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is perfectly supported, but you need to throw *an instance* of the exception!

The syntax of `throw` is basically:

```
throw [Throwable]
```

where `Throwable` is either an ErrorRecord, an Exception, or a string (a bare error message basically).

When you throw the type literal `[CustomException]`, PowerShell converts that expression to a `[string]`, which is why you just see the type name in the catch block.

Correctly throwing an exception instance requires you to call the constructor:

```bsh
class CustomException : Exception
{
  CustomException() : base("default CustomException message goes here")
  {
  }
}

try {
    throw [CustomException]::new()    # <-- don't forget to call the constructor
} catch {
    "$_"
}
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Ah, very interesting. Am I understanding right that this is unique to Powershell, or is that a nuance that just wasn't mentioned in the C# example? And, is it best practice to always is the constructor like this, or is `throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]` perfectly valid, so long as getting the type name as the message is acceptable? For consistency sake it feels like I might want to use `throw [CustomException]::new('Another message')` as well.

Comment: `throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]` actually results in `throw 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'` - it's valid, but it's not actually throwing an exception of the type you're expecting

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Is that because [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] resolves to a string via .ToString()? Not so much that it matters as I wonder if I am starting to understand stuff finally.

Comment: @Gordon yeah, exactly! `throw` only accepts three types of arguments: ErrorRecord's, Exception's or strings, so if not one of the two first, powershell converts to string